# Exporting data out of SharePoint into Excel

Tags: excel, export, excel-services

This is almost more of an Excel question than a SharePoint one, but I want to be able to pull specific data out of a SharePoint list into excel dynamically.

Specifically, I don't want to export a list into excel and then try to metabolize it. I'm curious if it's possible to make excel retrieve data from a field or fields in the list. Does SharePoint even allow you to pull list data out like that, or can it only be exported manually?

Comment: If you're not against coding you could also create a short console application that could query the SP list using CAML to return the specific information you want and generate a CSV file from it. This would be more of a one-time-use thing though rather than a data connection as Eric suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating a filtered view in your SharePoint list that narrows down the result set for you, then connect to this view in Excel to pull the data for whatever you need.

Comment: Adding to this, you can also save the Excel sheet and refresh the data from within the sheet so that you don't have to manually export each time.  It will maintain the link to the data for you.

Comment: That works! Thank you for the information its most helpful!